# Groovy DSL Spring cloud contract throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException for query parameter having Unicode Characters

Tags: java, groovy, unicode, spring-cloud-contract, groovydsl

I created a groovy DSL contract like below

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    final def NAME_REGEX = '[A-Za-z0-9\\u00C0-\\u00FF\'\\- ]{1,70}'

    request {
        method 'GET'
        url('/api/getEmployess') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'name': $(c(regex(NAME_REGEX)), p('\u00CAdward J\u00F5hnson'))
            }
        }
        headers {
            contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        }
    }
    response {
        status OK()
        body([
                [
                 id           : $(p(regex(nonBlank())), c('5a0eaf2012a9a12f1c98947a')),
                 name         : fromRequest().query("name")
               ]
        ])
        headers { contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8") }
    }
}
```

My service implementation returns 'name' and 'id' in response. In response, 'name' is Unicode value 'Êdward Jõhnson' which fails to match with the request parameter value.

I am getting below error -

```
Parsed JSON [[{"id":"5a0eaf2012a9a12f1c98947a","name":"Êdward Jõhnson"}]] doesn't match the JSON path [$[*][?(@.['name'] == 'ÃŠdward JÃµhnson')]]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parsed JSON [[{"id":"5a0eaf2012a9a12f1c98947a","name":"Êdward Jõhnson" }]] doesn't match the JSON path [$[*][?(@.['name'] == 'ÃŠdward JÃµhnson')]]
    at com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert.JsonAsserter.check(JsonAsserter.java:228)
    at com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert.JsonAsserter.checkBufferedJsonPathString(JsonAsserter.java:267)
```

I tried to pass the Unicode value in two ways in 'name' request query param -

1. Putting Unicode characters as Unicode numbers like in the above example -
   parameter 'name': $(c(regex(NAME_REGEX)), p('**\u00CAdward J\u00F5hnson**'))
2. Putting Unicode characters as it is
   parameter 'name': $(c(regex(NAME_REGEX)), p('**Êdward Jõhnson**'))

But for both cases, I am getting the same error. There looks some encoding issue because my value **Êdward Jõhnson** is changed to **ÃŠdward JÃµhnson** as mentioned in error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: i think you should use `/[\p{L}\p{N}-']{1,70}/` regex to match what you want

Comment: @injecteer I don't want to support all languages. I have selected a subset of Unicode characters in regex but the problem is with groovy DSL contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. In response 'name' field producer I put the same value which was in the request 'name' field producer. It was failing due to different encoding applied by groovy on unicode value. It's just a workaround to fix the problem, not a proper final solution.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
     final def NAME_REGEX = '^[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ'\-\s]{1,70}$'

     request {
                   method 'GET'
                   url('/api/getEmployess') {
                      queryParameters {
                          parameter 'name': $(c(regex(NAME_REGEX)), p('Êdward Jõhnson'))
                      }
                   }
                   headers {
                      contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                   }
           }
    response {
        status OK()
        body([
               [
                 id : $(p(regex(nonBlank())), c('4b0eaf2012a9a12f1c98567c')),
                 name : $(p("Êdward Jõhnson"), c(fromRequest().body('$.name'))),
               ]
           ])
           headers { contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8") }
    }
 }
```